# Minimum value from two arrays

Tags: python, numpy, minimum

I have two arrays

```
a=([2,3,5])
```

and

```
b=([-2,3.2,10])
```

How can I get minimum value from these two arrays?

Expected answer is -2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if a = [2, 3, 5] and b = [-2, 3.2, 10] then in Python:

```
result = min(min(a),min(b))
```

Answer (score 5):

Just find minimum of minimums:

```
min(min(a),min(b))
```

Answer (score 4):

Easy as Python:

```
a=([2,3,5])
b=([-2,3.2,10])

result = min(a + b)
```

Result: `-2`

Answer (score 0):

`min(a+b)` add the two arrays and use the min function to find the min

Comment: While your code may correct as answer But Elaborating what your code does, It can improve the quality of your answer. Checkout the Article : [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)